# I uninstalled Network Manager in Linux Mint and can't boot into it now

Tags: linux, boot, linux-mint

I was trying to install WICD instead of Network Manager to see if it could fix speed issues. Now I am getting an error:

The error is:
`unable to launch "cinnamon-session-cinnamon" X session ---
"cinnamon-session-cinnamon" not found; falling back to default session.`
If you click okay, there is a black screen with cursor moving.

I read somewhere there you have to press ctrl-alt-f1 but I dual-booted Linux on mac and alt is above option key and it's not working. Additionally, when I restart the computer, within like 3 seconds it goes to login screen. I can't see anything about getting into the BIOS or anything.

Comment: Reinstall Linux... it only takes a few minutes.

Comment: What about the data ? There is no restoring this ?

Comment: Copy off your data, *then* reinstall.

Comment: I can’t even boot into system. How would I copy data ?

Comment: You don't need to boot from the HDD. Use a live installation USB, mount the HDD, and copy off the data (or make a disk image with dd). Reinstall, and restore what you've saved.